# How to configure Azure STRATO Blockchain LTS with Visual Studio?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, microsoft-azure, visual-studio

I'm learning all about Blockchain but I wanted to make an example of smart contract, i followed [this tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlOrx.png), but I can't find much about how to integrate Azure Strato Blockchain with my application in Visual Studio, I read that I need to change the configuration file "Config.yaml" and put my public IP with the /strato-api/, but it does not work, I'm asking for tutorials that works with Azure STRATO Blockchain because I can't find any.

This is the error im getting by deploying the contract. [image]